# How to send a one time mailshot to 70k subscribers avoiding spam filter

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have been collecting emails via opt-in mailing list on one of my websites for a year now and have gained around 70k emails.

I want to now send out a one-time mailshot to them all promoting a new product.  I have used `PHPMailer` in the past to send out mails but they usually end up in the junk folder.  How best can I send these emails out without [a] crippling my server and [b] ending up in the spam filters.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are not 100% safe to not get into spam filters.

Things you could do to avoid blacklisting:

1. Use a programm like "SendBlaster" (good features are bounce mail report, import contact lists, individual subject and text for every mail) - Its always good that the mail content is not exactly 100% the same.
2. Don't use external links, pictures or other external content in your sended mail.
3. To be safe, send a plain text email.
4. Set a SPF record, this gives your sended mails some trust (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)
5. Mix up the 70k mails so that the time between mails that gets sended to the same domain is a big as possible

All 5 points are from my own experience with bulk lists from 2 to 5k

Answer (score 0):

Using a third party service would be your safest/easiest bet.

Chances are your server may already be blacklisted for spam, at the very least you'll have to write some form of looping cronjob to send the emails and set all the correct headers - there are so many issues that a dedicated service can overcome for a small cost.